# Is there a way to kill Brook?

Tags: one-piece

Is there any possibility of Brook dying?

[image]

I mean, you can't really kill him, because his soul always comes back.
Do you have to destroy his bones? But if I remember right, the Samurai on Thriller Bark broke a part of his skull. But now it healed, so is there no way that Brook can die?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that he would drown in the sea. Even though that he has no lungs. Yohohoho!

Comment: Doesn't the fact he has no lungs disprove that? Unless is there another reason it would work?

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko Devil fruit, any form that eating devil fruit will drown in sea

Comment: Throwing him in water. Every devil fruit user losses their ability in water and drowns.

Comment: But Brook has nu lungs. So he would just life forever under water?

Comment: but his power is to move his soul out of his skeleton so his soul may die

Comment: i agree with you, he can't move his soul, because he loose this ability under water, but it don't mean his soul dies...

Comment: ya you are right, his skeleton should be broked under water with time that may be the only way under water because his soul is linked to his body after skeleton broked away his soul might die

Comment: yeah, this could be. if he were still a normal human we couldn't discuss about this, but to kill a skeleton...
maybe he is immortal xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made a mistake in thinking his soul could come back as many times as it pleases. A Yomi Yomi no Mi user can only be resurrected once. He does seem immortal as we have seen him be beheaded and damaged several times, from which he had healed back by drinking calcium rich drinks such as milk. The only two possibilities there are to killing him is by either submerging him into water or by crushing his entire body forcing the soul to leave the body. This would indeed make him quite immortal.

**How many times does the Yomi Yomi no Mi resurrect the soul?**

[The wiki page on the Yomi Yomi no Mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Yomi_Yomi_no_Mi) states:

> The major strength of the fruit, as demonstrated by Brook, is that it gives its user another life after dying **once** before.

[The wiki page on Brook](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Brook/Abilities_and_Powers) states:

> While he was still alive, Brook ate the Yomi Yomi no Mi, a Paramecia-class Devil Fruit. Should the user of this fruit die, it allows them the **one-time** opportunity to return to life.

**Will the soul be able to come back regardless of the state of the user's body?**

[The wiki page on the Yomi Yomi no Mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Yomi_Yomi_no_Mi) states:

> After death, the user continues to exist in whatever state they were revived as and can even go as far as to grant a form of "immortality" that lasts until the user suffers a second death. This of course is **negated if the user's cause of death was drowning, and their body remains in the water**, or if their body is completely destroyed.

**What will kill a Yomi Yomi no Mi Devil Fruit user?**

[The wiki page on Brook](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Brook/Abilities_and_Powers) states:

> One advantage is that because he is just comprised of light weighted bones, he can use his speed and light weight to run across water, but, like all Devil Fruit users, he can still **drown when submerged**.

[The wiki page on the Yomi Yomi no Mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Yomi_Yomi_no_Mi) states:

> After death, the user continues to exist in whatever state they were revived as and can even go as far as to grant a form of "immortality" that lasts until the user suffers a second death. This of course is **negated** if the user's cause of death was drowning, and their body remains in the water, or **if their body is completely destroyed**.

**What will *not* kill a Yomi Yomi no Mi Devil Fruit user?**

[The wiki page on Brook](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Brook/Abilities_and_Powers) states:

> He has also proven that calcium (such as in milk) will rapidly heal any **damaged bones**.

If the user's **bones are only partially destroyed**, he will be able to regenerate them through consumption of calcium. Eg This was seen after Brook fought Ryuma and was severely damaged.

[image: Milk !]

[The wiki page on the Yomi Yomi no Mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Yomi_Yomi_no_Mi) states:

> As long as his bones are not hurt any attacks will not go to his core like when Zeo **beheaded** Brook, his soul managed to repair it and connect his bones together again.

[image: Zeo !]

Comment: Thank you, your answers are always great and very informative.  thx

Answer (score 3):

Brook can be killed, but it's not overly easy. Busoshoku haki lets you strike the true body of a devil fruit user, which would allow you to hit whatever he's possessing with a haki-infused axe and strike his soul.

So yeah, he is killable, but only if you have sufficient haki and strength.

Comment: This is just speculation, as it hasn't been stated in the show so I didn't include it in my answer, but my understanding is that if you literally ground Brook's bones to dust he would still be alive, as he is now just his soul, which happens to be possessing his bones.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Wiki for the Yomi-Yomi no Mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Yomi_Yomi_no_Mi), the person who eats it revives *once*. So Brook can still just as easily be killed, as he will not revive again.

Comment: yeah once, but how do you kill a sceleton? :'D

Answer (score 1):

It was mentioned in the anime that if you smash his spine really good he will die. Can't look for prooflink right now. At fishmen island as far as I remember, during the fight...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to degenerate his bones, acid is your best bet, especially HCl as it attacks calcium, you can try on a piece of chalk or some chicken bone.

And don't let him touch any milk in the process as it may regenerate him.

So, maybe any kind of food that is not calcium friendly can help, such as cassava or some very sour fruits.

Answer (score 0):

Killing brook might be nearly impossible. The methods normally used for killing devil fruit users might not apply to him because,

1. He's too light to drown and he has no lungs. So even if someone submerges him into the sea, he'll just lie there but wont die as he doesn't suffocate.
2. His soul returned to him after his body decomposes completely and the only thing left of his body are bones. So you'll need to completely destroy his body until nothing is left.

Had his soul returned to him when he still had his body and organs, It would be possible to kill him. Even submerging him underwater might had killed him as he would have lungs and lose his breath(The soul would attach to his living body which can be killed).
But now his soul is attached to his bones and will stay within them until they are completely obliterated.

You can think of him as darth nihilius of one piece.