# What would have happened if Brook Died from eating a Second Devil Fruit?

Tags: one-piece

I saw a post about "Creating your own Devil Fruit Powers".. Most OP would be having two abilities. Then I remember that eating Two Devil Fruits = your body to explode.

So.. I was thinking, What would have been the Result if Brook (Alive) would have died by eating a second Devil Fruit? Would his Yomi Yomi no Mi powers activate and revive him and if so, he is a person that was able to eat two devil fruit and live which means, two abilities?

Comment: This is only speculation, but if his body exploded, then there would be nothing for the soul to go back to, right? So I suppose the soul would have left for the after life as if [Brook would have been killed](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/9823/6166)?

Comment: [@mod-that-closed-as-duplicate](http://anime.stackexchange.com/users/63) This isn't a duplicate. What OP is asking, is whether a Revive Fruit user would still revive if he had died due to eating 2 fruits.

Comment: @PeterRaeves this is essentially asking the same topic answered in multiple other questions, but in a different way. [This answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5261/can-brook-have-another-devil-fruit) states that he cannot have another fruit and the main power is not "revival." [This answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/9823/is-there-a-way-to-kill-brook) explains the weaknesses of the fruit user eating two fruits.

Comment: The fruits can't revive if the body [explodes without a trace](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22090/what-will-happen-if-one-person-eats-two-devil-fruits). Brook's fruit is no exception.

Comment: @ʇosɥıuonʞʎonʞo Yes, that's indeed the answer to this question. I agree that an answer can be formed with the answers you linked to, but that doesn't make them the same questions.

Answer (score 1):

From my interpretation of your question I believe that according to what we know about what happens to people who eat two fruits. I will reference a few things as I go about answering your question.

**First**

The Revive-Revive Fruit that Brook possesses, also called the Yomi Yomi no Mi, is a Paramecia class that can bring the user back to life after death. But later in the series it is declared that the fruit has "further" capabilities and can enable several other things as referenced [here](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Yomi_Yomi_no_Mi). Brook uses these abilities in later episodes after the timeskip. As he found the "true nature of his fruit". Now whether or not that means he **awakened his power** or not is still up to speculation at this point, but I suspect we will see more at the next arc.

**Second**

As shown [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22090/what-will-happen-if-one-person-eats-two-devil-fruits) and [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/can-blackbeard-consume-more-than-one-devil-fruit), there are a few special exceptions where a particular person can have more than one fruit, so it is **theoretically** possible for Brook to have multiple fruits.

**Conclusion**

Given that most folks can't have more than one Devil Fruit and that Brook's power **IS NOT** "used up", and referring [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5261/can-brook-have-another-devil-fruit) I will follow the fact from [here](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Mythbusters/Misunderstandings_and_Mistranslations):

> Myth: When you eat 2 Devil Fruits, the second fruit will replace the first fruit's power.
>
> **Fact:** Eiichiro Oda stated in one of his SBS that you cannot transfer the fruit's power to another person, if you take one bite of it the fruit becomes normal. This caused fans to think he meant if you eat the second Devil Fruit it will replace the first fruit but in Enies Lobby Arc, Lucci and Blueno said if you eat the second fruit after eating the first one, your body will explode and you will die.
>
> Fact: An exception to the rule stated above is Marshall D. Teach, user of the Yami Yami no Mi fruit, who stole the power of the Gura Gura no Mi fruit through some currently unknown means not related to eating it.

I believe that if Brook ate a second fruit, his body would explode. Upon which the Revive Fruit which is there would try to activate returning his soul to his body, but due to no longer having a body via an explosion his soul would be trapped in the physical world but without a body to be in. Therefore he'd live but without a second ability, body or any method to do anything. He'd be a mass of floating "conscience". That is unless his fruit enables a possession technique of sorts which we have not seen yet. I hope I either answered your question or provided enough to read to help you arrive to a better one.

**TLDR** Brook would die, revive and not have a body or a second power.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was established that the abilities of Yomi Yomi no Mi will activate only once. So Brook will die if he eats another DF and not come back

Quoting the wikia:

> The Yomi Yomi no Mi is a Paramecia-type Devil Fruit which enhances the user's soul to the point where they can come back to life **after dying once**, remaining alive until their body is sufficiently damaged, and to use several other soul-based abilities, making the user a Reviving Human.

Comment: What about before he died the first time, which is what OP is asking? If the Revive fruit had not been activated yet, would it activate if he died due to eating a second devils fruit, or would the second devils fruit negate his revive power when it killed him, meaning he never got revived to begin with.

Comment: Can't find the source, but I would agree with @Hikari on the belief that the body would explode. It has never been explicitly stated if the body would be destroyed due to the fruits, just Jyabura's (who I don't consider a source) saying so. Without a body, he would be trapped in the physical realm OR he would die since he can still die if his bod is damage (i.e. bones).

Answer (score 0):

It is a good thinking but it is not how the Yomi Yomi no Mi works. It can bring you soul back to the human world but the sould must find the body. Eating two DF makes you explode so there is nothing left to find. At least the skeleton has du be intact.